# Get exact GEO location like lat and long in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have created simple android application which take current `Latitude` and `Longitude` from `google api`. then it will store that data to `server`.
My problem is that every time when i am try to get the `Location` it show me different value. same place and same phone then also it fetches different data.
this problem is very critical because i am doing some functionality based on the difference of the `Latitude` and `Longitude`.
can you tell me how can i get the same lat and long in each devices ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does it display huge differences or just ~50-100m differences? Because GPS isn't exact (plus it depends on connections, ...).